# Fix connection string URL for callable in Java?

Tags: java, sql-server

I am writing some code in Java to connect to one of my databases. However, when I go to run the code the URL fails with the error:

`java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlserver://TOD0008A7B.KKL.COM\\TTSHRD21;databaseName=FED_TES`

I am not sure if I am doing something wrong or if I need to add an extra backslash. I realize its so simple but I still am unable to connect to the db.

```
String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://TOD0008A7B.KKL.COM\\\\TTSHRD21;databaseName=FED_TES";
```

Comment: try this jdbc:sqlserver://TOD0008A7B.KKL.COM;instanceName=TTSHRD21;databaseName=FED_TES

Comment: The Exception is telling you that i has no driver for sqlserver. Did you add the sqlserver driver library to the classpath?